# Google Maps API canot display content of infowindow

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, oracle-apex

I have a question that may sound silly. I wrote javascript code to integrate APEX. The purpose of this part is to show Google map according to address and have infowindow. The infowindow will show name as content, and it is a link which leads to the detail report of that guy. Problem is: infowindow works well for most of names in database, but shows no content (the link) with certain name. I do not find any special for these names, such as "Robert Allan Lockett". Here I attach code as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript"       src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">     </script>     
<script type="text/javascript">       
function initialize() {  

var myOptions = { zoom: 18, mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP};   
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions); 

var markerBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(); 
var point=new google.maps.LatLng(&P3006_TF_GEOCODING.);

markerBounds.extend(point);  
map.fitBounds(markerBounds); 

var listener = google.maps.event.addListener(map, "idle", function() {  
map.setZoom(map.getZoom()-4);  
google.maps.event.removeListener(listener);  
});  

var marker;

marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: new google.maps.LatLng(&P3006_TF_GEOCODING.), map: map }); 

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({    content: "&P3006_H_OFFENDER_NAME."});

var current_parameter ="&APP_ID.:216:&SESSION.::NO::P216_DETAIL:"+"&P3006_H_OFFENDER_ID.";
var my_URL="http://lsg-solutions.com:9704/apex/f?p="+encodeURIComponent(current_parameter);


infowindow.setContent('<a href='+my_URL+'>&P3006_H_OFFENDER_NAME.</a>');

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {   infowindow.open(map,marker);});


}     
</script>
```

Comment: Can you link to your live implementation?  Also, is this going to be a public web site?

Comment: please show us the parsed output(browser->viewsource)

Comment: Yes, Guys, Thanks for your help!. You could try the following link: http://lsg-solutions.com:9704/apex/f?p=206:21

Comment: Yes, Guys, Thanks for your help!. You could try the following link: http://lsg-solutions.com:9704/apex/f?p=206:21     If you search by first name as "Robert", it is case sensitive. and if you try the name in the list as "Robert Allan Lockett" or "Robert B Ashley" and click the map link. you will find the name is not displayed in the infowindow, but other's name can be displayed without problem. Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: The problem is in your server side code, it is not populating the "name" on the page.  As Dr.Molle suggested, view the source of the problem page and compare it to a "good" page